# How come that `docker-compose up` throws an error where `docker run` works fluently

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to set-up an environment for development & production of an NodeJS application with Docker. For the development environment I try to run the application with nodemon (since this watches for file changes). But when I try to run it with `docker-compose up`, I get the following error:

**ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"nodemon\": executable file not found in $PATH"**

When I run `docker run web-app` (the web-app image is generated with `docker build -t web-app .` I have no problems at all. I would like to know how this different behavior occurs, and how to resolve it. Below I've put the files I've got for simpler understanding of the problem.

---

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:latest

# Install nodemon globally
RUN npm i nodemon -g

# Add local directory to /node/web-app
ADD . /node/web-app
# Switch to /node/web-app
WORKDIR /node/web-app

# Install NPM dependencies
RUN npm install

# Run nodemon
CMD ["nodemon", "."]
```

---

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:   
web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
   command:
     - nodemon .
```

Comment: It seems too weird for me. I tried an example and worked fine. Are you sure that you are running the same image in both cases?

Comment: Hi @Robert I found the problem, I have updated my original post. In my docker-compose file I have "command: - nodemon .", adding that line throws the error, removing that line resolves the problem. I still don't understand what difference this makes though. =/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, seeing your comments. I realize what is the problem. The `command` directive in the docker-compose.yml should not be a list.

Write it as string:

```
command: nodemon .
```

But, as the same command is already declared in Dockerfile, it is not necessary at all to put it in docker-compose.yml

---

Edit: It is possible to write the command as a list, but you need to sepparate each parameter:

```
command:
  - nodemon
  - .
```